# Sobolev spaces: Show using Fourier transformation that the delta distribution is in $H^{-1} (\mathbb{R})$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform

I have already shown that the $\delta$-distribution is in $H^{-s}(\mathbb{R}), s>n/2$:

Every function $\phi \in H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is continuous hence it can be evaluated at a point so using Sobolev embedding theorem we can say:

$|\delta(\phi)|=|\phi(0)| \leq ||\phi||_{\infty}=||\phi||_{C_b(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leq C||\phi||_{H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)}$

Hence $\delta$ is a continuous linear functional on $H^s(\mathbb{R})$.

Now I need to show using Fourier transformation that $\delta \in H^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$. So what I want to show is that $||\phi||_{\infty} \leq C||\phi||_{H^{1}(\mathbb{R)}}$. Now if we denote $F^{-1}$ as the inverse Fourier transformation we get:

$||\phi||_{\infty}=||F^{-1} \overline{\phi}||_\infty=\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{1/2}}|\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{ix.\xi}\overline{\phi}(\xi)d\xi| \leq \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{1/2}}\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|e^{ix.\xi}||\overline{\phi}(\xi)|d\xi \leq \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{1/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\overline{\phi}(\xi)|d\xi $

(Why is the supremum attained at $x=0$? Or why does the $e$ vanish?)

Now $C||\phi||_{H^1(\mathbb{R})}=C(\int_\mathbb{R}(1+|\rho|^2)|\overline{\phi}(\rho)|^2d\rho)^{1/2}$

Now I'm unsure how to compare these two integrals. I'm especially unsure about the $^{1/2}$ in the norm.

Is it correct what I have shown up to now and how could I continue?

Comment: Note that more generally we have the inequality $$\lVert{f}\rVert_{C^{k-\frac np}(\mathbb R^n)}\lesssim \lVert f\rVert_{W^{k, p}(\mathbb R^n)}$$ for all $p\in[1,\infty[$, $k\in\mathbb N$ and $n\in\mathbb N$ with $kp>n$ and $f\in W^{ḱ,p}(\mathbb R^n)$. This is Morrey's embedding, cf. Theorems 12.48 and 12.55  in *A First Course on Sobolev Spaces* by Giovanni Leoni for the precise statement and proof. Setting $ p=2,n=1, k=1$ gives what you want immediately.

Comment: Indeed, we have $|e^{i x\cdot\xi}|=1$ for all $x$ and $\xi$: recall [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula). For the second question, I would suggest you to write $\int_{\mathbb R}|\bar{\phi}(\xi)|\,d\xi=\int (1+|\xi|^2)^{-1/2}(1+|\xi|^2)^{1/2}|\bar{\phi}(\xi)|\,d\xi$ and then apply Cauchy-Schwartz inequality to get $\int_{\mathbb R}|\bar{\phi}(\xi)|\,d\xi\leq C\|\phi\|_{H^1}$.

Comment: Another thing: I have never seen the notation $\bar{\phi}$ to denote the Fourier tranform of $\phi$. In all materials I get touched with, they use $\hat{\phi}$. So I recommend you to follow the more propular notation, or, you should mention the meaning of $\bar{\phi}$ before using this notation.

Comment: OP, do you know that Sobolev embedding also holds in the case $n=1$?

Comment: You say you proved that is is in any $H^{-s}(\Bbb R^n)$ with $s>n/2$, so in particular, if $n=1$, then it works for $s=1$ ... ??

Comment: Yes, but the task was to show it again for $s=1$ but using Fourier transformation.